# All possible combinations of elements in vector with repetitions in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, combinations

I have 6 numbers with repetition: 1,2,2,3,3,4. I want all possible combinations using any 4 of the numbers. How will I get that in MATLAB?

Generally I use 'nchoosek' function if there is no repetition.

Example: `A = 1:6; combinations = nchoosek(A,4);`

Comment: Could you provide the expected outcome of the example? Is it `unique(nchoosek(A,4),'rows')`?

Comment: @Arpi I think that `nchoosek(unique(A),4)` will be more effective.

Comment: You can use `nchoosek` on the indices of your array.

Comment: @Adiel In that case you wouldn't get combinations with repeated values, e.g. `[1,2,2,3]`. But let's wait for the expected outcome.

Comment: @Arpi sure, that what I thought he wanted, because he wrote that if there is no repetition he would use `nchoosek`... But he definitely should clarify his question.

Answer (score 1):

[`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) is sufficient for this task, and includes repetitions.

```
A = [1 2 2 3 3 4];
combinations = nchoosek(A, 4);
```

If you would have wanted not to include any repetitions, you would have done:

```
combinations = nchoosek(unique(A), 4);
```

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but this yields to the same output as `nchoosek(A,4)`.

Comment: Indeed! I assumed without checking that this wouldn't be the behavior because of the question, but it seems `nchoosek(A,4)` is sufficient. I'll edit the answer.